# Java JDBC+Spring Connection closing

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, connection

I have a simple class that can search all tables in PostgreSQL and generate a `SELECT` query for them. Works fine but need advice on closing java.sql.Connection
I'd like my object to keep the database connection while the instance still exists. To do this, I created a private `Connection connection` field so that the connection to the database is not established and closed after each method is called (during one session), but is created once and closed after the main thread stops or after the bean is disposed of. I tried to use `@PreDestroy` and implement a `DisposableBean` interface but didn't see any clear result. So what is the correct approach to close such a connection?

QueryBuilder class

```
@Component
public class PostgreSQLQueryBuilder implements SQLQueryBuilder{

    private DatabaseMetaData metaData;
    private Connection connection; // I need to close this somehow

    @Autowired
    public PostgreSQLQueryBuilder(DataSource dataSource) {
        try {
            this.connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            this.metaData = connection.getMetaData();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String queryForTable(String tableName){
        String resultQuery = null;
        List<String> columnList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (getTables().contains(tableName)) {
            try (ResultSet columns = metaData.getColumns(null, null, tableName, null)) {
                //some logic
                return resultQuery;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return resultQuery;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getTables() {
        List<String> tables = new ArrayList<>();
        try (ResultSet schemaRs = metaData.getSchemas()) {
            while (schemaRs.next()) {
                String currentSchema = schemaRs.getString(1);
                try (ResultSet tableRS = metaData.getTables(null, currentSchema, "%", new String[]{"TABLE", "SYSTEM TABLE"})) {
                    while (tableRS.next()) {
                        tables.add(tableRS.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tables;
    }
    // I tried this
    @PreDestroy
    private void closeConnections(){
        try{
           this.connection.close()
           //this is not printed
           System.out.println("Connection closed")
        }catch(Exception e){
           //some logic
        }
    }
}
```

Testing class:

```
public class SQLQueryExtenderTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
    applicationContext.start();
    SQLQueryBuilder queryBuilder = applicationContext.getBean(SQLQueryBuilder.class);
    List<String> tables = queryBuilder.getTables();
    System.out.println(tables);
    System.out.println(queryBuilder.queryForTable("some_table"));
    System.out.println(queryBuilder.queryForTable("person"));
    System.out.println(queryBuilder.queryForTable(null));
    }
//I expect the connection to be closed at this point
}
```

Comment: Are you  using some connection pool?

Comment: PreDestroy is the right one. Please check the Java version in use. If 11+ then add a dependency for javax.annotation-api

Comment: @Mar-Z adding the dependency was the first thing I did!! Still no result:(

Comment: Ditch your approach and inject the `JdbcTemplate` from Spring, that together with proper transaction management will do proper resource manageme.t